# Deploy war on tomcat by hudson using maven cargo plugin

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, hudson, hudson-plugins

i am using Hudson for CI . I have used copy artifact plugin which copies newly formed build to maven repository and maven's cargo plugin is used to deploy war on tomcat7x container.When there id no war in tomcat webapps and Hudson job is scheduled build is deployed successfullt on tomcat but when i am scheduling my Hudson job next time build is created successfully but when deployed on tomcat container i am getting exception.

```
[INFO] Copying 68 resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] [war:war {execution: default-war}]
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [epdei] in [C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace\target\epdei]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [34667 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace\target\epdei.war
[INFO] [install:install {execution: default-install}]
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace\target\epdei.war to C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.m2\repository\epdei\epdei\2.3.0.RELEASE\epdei-2.3.0.RELEASE.war
[HUDSON] Archiving C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace\pom.xml to C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\modules\epdei$epdei\builds\2012-10-23_15-47-30\archive\epdei\epdei\2.3.0.RELEASE\pom.xml
[HUDSON] Archiving C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace\target\epdei.war to C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\modules\epdei$epdei\builds\2012-10-23_15-47-30\archive\epdei\epdei\2.3.0.RELEASE\epdei.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 38 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 23 15:50:16 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/265M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
channel stopped
Deploying artifacts to file:///C:/Users/rohit.kumar/.m2/repository
Deploying the main artifact epdei.war
Deploying C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace\target\epdei.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
  The property cargo.tomcat.manager.url has been deprecated, please use cargo.remote.uri instead.
  Redeploying [C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace\target\epdei.war]
  Undeploying [C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace\target\epdei.war]
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to undeploy [C:\Users\rohit.kumar\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace\target\epdei.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:176)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:62)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:92)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:75)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:75)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:45)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:630)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:608)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:811)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:553)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1390)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:414)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\webapps\epdei]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.

    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:529)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:443)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.undeploy(TomcatManager.java:383)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.performUndeploy(Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:128)
    ... 17 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\webapps\epdei]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.

    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:529)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:443)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.undeploy(TomcatManager.java:383)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.performUndeploy(Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:176)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:62)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:92)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:75)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:75)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:45)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:630)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:608)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:811)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:553)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1390)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:414)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: test #43 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

my cargo plugin configuration is :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <configuration> 
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                    <type>installed</type>
                </container> 
                <configuration>
                    <type>existing</type>
                    <home>C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28</home>
                </configuration>               
                    <deployer>
                        <type>installed</type>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>epdei</groupId>
                                <artifactId>epdei</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <properties>
                                <context>/epdei</context>
                                </properties>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </deployer>
            </configuration>            
        </plugin>
```

Can any tell me how to resolve this problum.

Comment: Error I saw in say that , it can not delete the existing war file.  Just check the permission to delete the file. Generally for each release we change the release number and war takes the release number as file name and rest you can maintain easily.